# Received invalid metadata error in produce request on partition topic-0 due to org.apache.kafka.common.errors.NotLeaderForPartitionException

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-cloud-stream

We use spring kafka stream producer to produce data to kafka topic. when we did resiliency test, we got the the below error.

`2020-08-28 16:18:35.536 WARN [,,,] 26 --- [ad | producer-3] o.a.k.clients.producer.internals.Sender : [Producer clientId=producer-3] Received invalid metadata error in produce request on partition topic1-0 due to org.apache.kafka.common.errors.NotLeaderForPartitionException: This server is not the leader for that topic-partition.. Going to request metadata update now

log: 2020-08-28 16:18:35.536 WARN [,,,] 26 --- [ad | producer-3] o.a.k.clients.producer.internals.Sender : [Producer clientId=producer-3] Got error produce response with correlation id 80187 on topic-partition topic1-0, retrying (4 attempts left). Error: NOT_LEADER_FOR_PARTITION

[Producer clientId=producer-3] Received invalid metadata error in produce request on partition topic1-0 due to org.apache.kafka.common.errors.NotLeaderForPartitionException: This server is not the leader for that topic-partition.. Going to request metadata update now.

The warn should be coming only for the period of time we are running resiliency(broker down/up testing) but these warning happening even after the resiliency test period and happening only for the particular partition(here topic1-0). all the other partitions are working fine.`

this is the producer config we have:
`spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.requiredAcks=all spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.configuration.retries=5 spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.configuration.metadata.max.age.ms=3000 spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.configuration.max.in.flight.requests.per.connection=1 spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.configuration.retry.backoff.ms=10000`

we have retry config too and it is retrying to get the proper metadata which you can see the above log but keep getting the same warning for that particular partition. Our kafka team also analyzing this issue. I checked google for any solution but nothing i could find to be useful.

is there any config or anything else missing?

please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Any update of how to resolved /catch this error?

Answer (score 0):

This error comes when Kafka is down. Restarting Kafka worked for me! :)